# redirect to same page to anchor

Tags: php, redirect

Need make redirect from http://sitename.com/cat/index.php to http://sitename.com/cat/index.php#anchor

I tried 2 ways: php redirect and meta refresh

**PHP redirect**

```
<?php
    $URL = "http://sitename.com/cat/index.php#anchor";
    header("Location: $URL");
?>
<html>
....
```

**meta refresh**

```
<html>
    <head>
    ... 
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=http://sitename.ru/cat/index.php#anchor">
    ...
    </head>
...
</html>
```

In result to both ways I have cycling page refresh.

**How to correctly solve this problem ?**

Comment: try the solution here : http://stackoverflow.com/a/506004/889678

Comment: Thank you. It works as I want.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't need to redirect the page, just set the `window.location.hash`.

```
window.location.hash="anchor";
```

Comment: This is true way for a my question. Thx you.

Comment: @xdazz Is it possible to solve this without using javascript?